# Creating a flutter application for Raspberry Pi os

Tags: linux, flutter, dart, raspberry-pi

I am willing to create a flutter application for my raspberry pi 4, but I want to create the application completely on my windows machine and then build and deploy to raspberry pi . What should be the basic things I need to setup before starting to create the application

I tried researching a lot on the internet but can't find many resources

Answer (score 0):

You can watch [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5C90jVS7xg) to get an idea how to run flutter in rasberry pi using **flutter-pi** then:

1. Install [flutter-pi](https://github.com/ardera/flutter-pi) to run flutter application in *rasberry-pi*.
2. At step **Building apps** you can use [cabin demo](https://github.com/KDAB/cabin-demo) sample program instead of *flutter_gallery*. Build, copy and run it then you get an idea how flutter apps runs.
3. Learn how to build an app using *Flutter* by [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKueYVtV0eA&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jLYyp2Aoh6hcWuxFDX6PBJ&index=3).
4. Build your own and run it on *rasberry-pi* using *flutter-pi*. Or learn from [cabin demo](https://github.com/KDAB/cabin-demo) code how to build an flutter app.

Good luck for your journey.